# SetProp(…) fails for console windows on XP

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-xp

I'm trying to use the [SetProp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633568%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function in the Windows API, but on my XP-32bit SP3 system it always fails with `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` (5) when given a handle to a console window, while on Windows 7 it seems to work fine.

This C program demonstrates the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
void main() {
    {
        HWND Wnd = GetConsoleWindow();
        SetLastError(ERROR_SUCCESS);
        int Success = SetPropW(Wnd, L"asdf", (HANDLE) 0xdeadbeef);
        int Error = GetLastError();

        printf("console (%x)\n", Wnd);
        printf("\tsuccess: %u\n", Success); // 0 - failed
        printf("\terror: %u\n", Error); // 5 - ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED
        printf("\tprop: %x\n\n", (unsigned) GetPropW(Wnd, L"asdf"));
    };

    {
        HWND Wnd = GetDesktopWindow();
        SetLastError(ERROR_SUCCESS);
        int Success = SetPropW(Wnd, L"asdf", (HANDLE) 0xdeadbeef);
        int Error = GetLastError();

        printf("desktop (%x)\n", Wnd);
        printf("\tsuccess: %u\n", Success); // 1 - succeeded
        printf("\terror: %u\n", Error); // 0 - ERROR_SUCCESS
        printf("\tprop: %x\n\n", (unsigned) GetPropW(Wnd, L"asdf"));
    };
};
```

It does seem to affect console windows that are unrelated to the current process as well, and I haven't found any visible non-console windows which cause this.

What gives? The only thing the documentation for SetProp says about this is

> When UIPI [User Interface Privilege Isolation] blocks property changes, GetLastError will return 5

but UIPI doesn't exist on XP, and it works fine on Windows 7 which does have UIPI.

I checked the function's source in the Wine and ReactOS implementations, but there doesn't seem to be any way they could behave like this. The actual Microsoft implementation seems to be mostly just a system call (0x1213 on my OS), <strike>so I have no means of analysing it</strike>. (update: [win32k.sys NtUserSetProp disassembly](http://pastebin.com/2vFkvx1f) )

If anyone can think of a workaround I'd be very interested to hear it.

Extra code: [http://pastebin.com/RmJHxRPF - tests every window on the current desktop](http://pastebin.com/RmJHxRPF)

---

For reference, the scenario where I'm facing this issue is: I'm writing a desktop shell, and would like to store metadata on windows that persists as long as the window exists (even if my shell process stops running).

Comment: A console window is owned by another process.  Conhost.exe on modern versions of Windows, csrss.exe on old versions.  You can see it back in Task Manager.  Its primary purpose is to act as a security boundary, stopping other processes from messing with the window.  This is supposed to fail, you can only get ahead when you stop trying.

Comment: @HansPassant the desktop window is also owned by csrss.exe, and I have no problems setting properties on that.

Comment: You aren't checking for errors properly. Check the return value.

Comment: Also see: [What's so special about the desktop window?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/24/79212.aspx)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan SetProp never sets the last error when it succeeds, and neither do GetDesktopWindow or GetConsoleWindow

Comment: You aren't checking the return value. Why not?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan honestly I just forgot; I've edited the code in the question now

Comment: That's better. That at least removes one explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system call for setting window properties is `NtUserSetProp` in `%windir%\system32\win32k.sys`. Here's roughly what it does (in pseudo-C, based on [the disassembly](http://pastebin.com/2vFkvx1f)):

```
NtUserSetProp(hwnd, atom, value) {

    WND* esi = ValidateHwnd(hwnd); // call win32k!ValidateHwnd; mov esi,eax
    if (!esi) {return;}; // test esi,esi; jz win32k!NtUserSetProp+0x95

    // check if the window is the current thread's desktop's main window (THREADINFO.rpdesk.pDeskInfo.spwnd)
    THREADINFO* eax = gptiCurrent; // mov eax,[win32k!gptiCurrent]
    DESKTOP* eax = eax.rpdesk; // mov eax,[eax+0x3c]
    DESKTOPINFO* eax = eax.pDeskInfo; // mov eax,[eax+0x4]
    if (eax.spwnd == esi) {// cmp [eax+0x8],esi
        // SetPropW(GetDesktopWindow(), ...) takes this path
        goto SetTheProperty; // jz SetTheProperty
    };

    // check if the process associated with the window (WND.pti.ppi) is NOT in the same session as the current process
    EPROCESS* eax = PsGetCurrentProcess(); // call win32k!_imp__PsGetCurrentProcess
    PROCESSINFO* eax = PsGetProcessWin32Process(eax); // call win32k!_imp__PsGetProcessWin32Process
    THREADINFO* ecx = esi.pti; // mov ecx,[esi+0x8]
    PROCESSINFO* ecx = ecx.ppi; // mov ecx,[ecx+0x2c]
    DWORD eax = eax.luidSession.LowPart; // mov eax,[eax+0x160]
    if (eax != ecx.luidSession.LowPart) {// cmp eax,[ecx+0x160]
        // SetPropW(GetConsoleWindow(), ...) takes this path
        goto Fail; // jnz win32k!NtUserSetProp+0x69;
    };
    //repeat for luidSession.HighPart

    SetTheProperty : {
        return InternalSetProp(esi, atom, value); // call win32k!InternalSetProp
    };

    Fail : {
        UserSetLastError(5); // call win32k!UserSetLastError
        return; // jmp win32k!NtUserSetProp+0x93
    };
};
```

All the actual work is done by `InternalSetProp`. `NtUserSetProp`'s only purpose is to check that the process associated with the window is running in the same session (`PROCESSINFO.luidSession`) as the process calling the function. Console windows on XP are created by the **csrss.exe** service, which runs on a different session from the user, despite the windows actually opening in the user's session, so `NtUserSetProp` fails. It makes an exception for setting properties on the user session's desktop window (`GetDesktopWindow()`), which is also created by csrss.

On Windows 7 and later, csrss is no longer responsible for console management — **conhost.exe** fills this role, which does run in the user's session, so `NtUserSetProp` has no complaints.

### Solution

I elected to simply patch the function so it never fails, which actually turns out to be pretty easy. I loaded my win32k.sys in OllyDbg as a data file, and switched the window to the 'disassemble' view. The hardest part might be locating the function — in my win32k.sys (crc32: edb43324), `NtUserSetProp` starts at offset 0x282F4.

I then removed (replaced with `nop`s) the jumps after the `luidSession` comparisons (one for `luidSession.LowPart`, one for `luidSession.HighPart`), as in this diagram:
[image: patchin' dat dwiver]

There's one additional step needed to complete the patch: Windows refuses to load kernel modules that don't include a matching checksum in their PE header, so the checksum must be corrected to match our modified file. The [ARTeam CheckSum Fixer](http://accessroot.com/arteam/site/download.php?view.239) can sort this out for us:
[image: ARTeam CheckSum Fixer]

And we're done. Backup your original win32k.sys and replace it with the patched copy.

As far as I can tell, this patch is working flawlessly. I'm not sure what an equivalent 'production-quality' solution would be though — maybe using another driver to patch the function in-memory, or adding a new system call which goes straight to `InternalSetProp`; I'm certainly open to suggestions.